# Using Regex with Lumen route

Tags: regex, lumen

I am trying to make a part of route case insensitive, so I tried using `(?i)` modifier in order achieve that:

```
(?i)my/route
```

However, there is a line in `nikic router` that Lumen is using

```
$regex .= preg_quote($part, '~');
```

that replaces regex parts of the url, and at the end my url looks like this:

```
/\(\?i\)my/route
```

Is there a way to put regex inside the url in Lumen that I'm not aware of?

Comment: How do you register your route?

Comment: I don't believe FastRoute can handle this.

Answer (score 6):

Here is how Lumen handles regexps 

   `$app->get('user/{id:[0-9]+}', 'PostController@profile');`

https://nikic.github.io/2014/02/18/Fast-request-routing-using-regular-expressions.html